# Passing parameters from javascript to JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i'm trying to write this next code. I have an image and a button. i want to change the button's value (title) when the image is clicked. can anyone tell me what's wrong here? (if u find stupid typos ignore it i wansn't copy pasting everything).

and another Q about the script part (maybe related to my problem): does the method request.getParameter(imageId) really returns the function's above parameter?

JSP:

```
<%

String messageButton = "Click me!";

%>

<%!

public void changeStatusButton(String i_MessageButton)
{
    i_MessageButton = "You Clicked The Image!";
}

%>
```

html head:

```
<script>

    button imageClicked(imageId) {

        <% changeStatusButton(request.getParameter(imageId)) %>    

    }

</script>
```

html body:

```
<input type="image" id="greatimage" onclick="imageClicked(id)"/>
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="<%=messageButton%>"/>
```

Comment: Is it just me or are you mixing server and client language here? And I also think your onclick="imageClicked(id) - id is undefined.

Comment: It's defined i just copy pasted it for you as a small chunk from a large code. and no i'm not mixing client server. everything is written in the same JSP file. Some value are taken from a tomcat server

Comment: I agree with Anze. You can't write code like `button imageClicked…`, that is client side code and I think browser can NOT understand them

Answer (score 1):

All the code that is within the scriptlets will be executed on the server side. No java code gets out from the server, all that comes out is HTML, even if they are all in the same JSP. Your JSP code should look like -

```
<% String messageButton = "Click me!"; %> // server-side code
<script type="text/javascript"> // client side code
    function imageClicked() {
        document.getElementById("mybutton").value = "You Clicked The Image!";
    }

</script>

<input type="image" id="greatimage" onclick="imageClicked();"/> // client side code
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="<%=messageButton%>"/> // client side code with <%=messageButton%> evaluated at server side.
```

So when the HTML code is generated, what gets out from the server and rendered in your browser is this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function imageClicked() {
        document.getElementById("mybutton").value = "You Clicked The Image!";
    }

</script>

<input type="image" id="greatimage" onclick="imageClicked();"/>
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Click me!"/>
```

Even your variable `messageButton` wont come to the client side because that is within scriptlet.